# WCHAR to String, how do i do it?

Tags: c++, windows, string, visual-c++, managed

```
String* Adder::downloadUrl(String* url)
{
    DWORD dwSize = 0;
    LPVOID lpOutBuffer = NULL;
    BOOL  bResults = FALSE;
    HINTERNET hSession = NULL,
              hConnect = NULL,
              hRequest = NULL;

    // Use WinHttpOpen to obtain a session handle.
    hSession = WinHttpOpen(  L"A WinHTTP Example Program/1.0",
                             WINHTTP_ACCESS_TYPE_DEFAULT_PROXY,
                             WINHTTP_NO_PROXY_NAME,
                             WINHTTP_NO_PROXY_BYPASS, 0);

    // Specify an HTTP server.
    if (hSession)
        hConnect = WinHttpConnect( hSession, L"www.google.com",
                                   INTERNET_DEFAULT_HTTP_PORT, 0);

    // Create an HTTP request handle.
    if (hConnect)
        hRequest = WinHttpOpenRequest( hConnect, L"GET", NULL,
                                       NULL, WINHTTP_NO_REFERER,
                                       WINHTTP_DEFAULT_ACCEPT_TYPES,
                                       0);

    // Send a request.
    if (hRequest)
        bResults = WinHttpSendRequest( hRequest,
                                       WINHTTP_NO_ADDITIONAL_HEADERS,
                                       0, WINHTTP_NO_REQUEST_DATA, 0,
                                       0, 0);

    // End the request.
    if (bResults)
        bResults = WinHttpReceiveResponse( hRequest, NULL);

    // First, use WinHttpQueryHeaders to obtain the size of the buffer.
    if (bResults)
    {
        WinHttpQueryHeaders( hRequest, WINHTTP_QUERY_RAW_HEADERS_CRLF,
                             WINHTTP_HEADER_NAME_BY_INDEX, NULL,
                             &dwSize, WINHTTP_NO_HEADER_INDEX);

        // Allocate memory for the buffer.
        if( GetLastError( ) == ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER )
        {
            lpOutBuffer = new WCHAR[dwSize/sizeof(WCHAR)];

            // Now, use WinHttpQueryHeaders to retrieve the header.
            bResults = WinHttpQueryHeaders( hRequest,
                                       WINHTTP_QUERY_RAW_HEADERS_CRLF,
                                       WINHTTP_HEADER_NAME_BY_INDEX,
                                       lpOutBuffer, &dwSize,
                                       WINHTTP_NO_HEADER_INDEX);
        }
    }

    // Print the header contents.
    if (bResults)
        printf("Header contents: \n%S",lpOutBuffer);

    // Free the allocated memory.
    delete [] lpOutBuffer;

    // Report any errors.
    if (!bResults)
        printf("Error %d has occurred.\n",GetLastError());

    // Close any open handles.
    if (hRequest) WinHttpCloseHandle(hRequest);
    if (hConnect) WinHttpCloseHandle(hConnect);
    if (hSession) WinHttpCloseHandle(hSession);


    String* retOne;

    return retOne;
}
```

I want to get response as string i am using dll in C#, dont know vc++ at all, please suggest a way.

String* retOne //how to get response;
return retOne;

**UPDATE**

```
// Convert a wide Unicode string to an UTF8 string
std::string utf8_encode(const std::wstring &wstr)
{
    int size_needed = WideCharToMultiByte(CP_UTF8, 0, &wstr[0], (int)wstr.size(), NULL, 0, NULL, NULL);
    std::string strTo( size_needed, 0 );
    WideCharToMultiByte (CP_UTF8, 0, &wstr[0], (int)wstr.size(), &strTo[0], size_needed, NULL, NULL);
    return strTo;
}
```

String* retOne = utf8_encode(lpOutBuffer);

Gives error: **'utf8_encode' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'LPVOID' to 'const std::wstring**

Please don't post comments suggesting use of .net libraries.

Comment: I have used c# never used c++, all the * and & :: in the code makes me feel dizzy.

Comment: String* and std::string are not the same. You utf8_encode function looks fine but it's creating a std::string not a String*. I've never heard of String so I would suggest you stop using it and use std::string though out your program. If you can't do that then you should at least explain what String is, it's not a standard C++ type.

Comment: I am using C++/CLI System String, for Managed Code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you need the [WideCharToMultiByte function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd374130%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: still giving error, pls can you provide more details, I am getting error, Please look at the Updates above.

Answer (score 1):

Whats hard in this process is to understand the function *WideCharToMultiByte*.

Basically what you need to do in order to get the whole string (and avoid garbage as a result of not having a null terminating string) is first use:

```
int size_needed = WideCharToMultiByte(CP_UTF8, 0, (LPCWCH)lpOutBuffer, -1, NULL, 0, NULL, NULL);
char *stringMe = new char[size_needed + 1];
```

While *size_needed* will be the required buffer size for [lpMultiByteStr](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd374130%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) in the *WideCharToMultiByte* function.

Afterwards you just need to use that function again, since now you have the complete size:

```
WideCharToMultiByte(CP_UTF8, 0, (LPCWCH)lpOutBuffer, -1, stringMe, size_needed, NULL, NULL);
stringMe[size_needed + 1] = NULL;
```

Now you can also convert it to String:

```
std::string serverOutput(stringMe);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 String* retOne = utf8_encode(std::wstring(lpOutBuffer));
```

or

```
 String* retOne = utf8_encode(std::wstring((WCHAR*)lpOutBuffer));
```